# Log on to user in lock screen with simulating key strokes using SendInput?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to use SendInput() function to login to my account like I would do in person;
press enter, press the password keys, press enter again.

The purpose of this is I wrote a remote connection program that I can get screenshots to check if everything's doing ok. The program starts with task scheduler so when my pc reboots I can still send commands and get screenshots. But I want to add a login option remotely so if my pc reboots I can remotely send signal to log in.

It works as intended in desktop but when I lock my user with win+L, It doesn't do anything in lock screen neither in desktop when I log on to check.

Here's the code

```cpp
void sendPassword(){

    //Map to store keys as char-WORD
    QMap<QString, WORD> keyMap;

    keyMap["Enter"] = 0x0D;
    
    keyMap["0"] = 0x30;    keyMap["1"] = 0x31;    keyMap["2"] = 0x32;    keyMap["3"] = 0x33;
    keyMap["4"] = 0x34;    keyMap["5"] = 0x35;    keyMap["6"] = 0x36;    keyMap["7"] = 0x37;
    keyMap["8"] = 0x38;    keyMap["9"] = 0x39;
    
    keyMap["A"] = 0x41;    keyMap["B"] = 0x42;    keyMap["C"] = 0x43;    keyMap["D"] = 0x44;
    keyMap["E"] = 0x45;    keyMap["F"] = 0x46;    keyMap["G"] = 0x47;    keyMap["H"] = 0x48;
    keyMap["I"] = 0x49;    keyMap["J"] = 0x4A;    keyMap["K"] = 0x4B;    keyMap["L"] = 0x4C;
    keyMap["M"] = 0x4D;    keyMap["N"] = 0x4E;    keyMap["O"] = 0x4F;    keyMap["P"] = 0x50;
    keyMap["Q"] = 0x51;    keyMap["R"] = 0x52;    keyMap["S"] = 0x53;    keyMap["T"] = 0x54;
    keyMap["U"] = 0x55;    keyMap["V"] = 0x56;    keyMap["W"] = 0x57;    keyMap["X"] = 0x58;
    keyMap["Y"] = 0x59;    keyMap["Z"] = 0x5A;

    //Get password from file.
    QFile passFile("password.txt");
    passFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QString password = QString::fromUtf8(passFile.readAll()).split("\r\n")[0].split("\n")[0];
    passFile.close();

    //Initialize inputs array.
    INPUT* inputs = new INPUT[password.length()*2+4] {};

    //Add enter button to inputs array, key down and up.
    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = keyMap["Enter"];

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = keyMap["Enter"];
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;


    for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++){
        
        //Add password to inputs array char by char, key down and up.
        inputs[i*2+2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inputs[i*2+2].ki.wVk = keyMap[(QString)password[i]];

        inputs[i*2+3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inputs[i*2+3].ki.wVk = keyMap[(QString)password[i]];
        inputs[i*2+3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    }

    //Add enter button to inputs array, key down and up.
    inputs[password.length()*2+2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[password.length()*2+2].ki.wVk = keyMap["Enter"];

    inputs[password.length()*2+3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[password.length()*2+3].ki.wVk = keyMap["Enter"];
    inputs[password.length()*2+3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    
    //SendInput, send inputs array.
    SendInput(password.length()*2+4, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));

    //Delete inputs array.
    delete[] inputs;
}
```

If this has no way to work, then how can I reach my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a git repository.

You can access it here,

[Winlogon](https://github.com/kayakaan02/Winlogon)

edit after @Prashant's reply:

So the actual answer that led me to solve this is @Derek's answer, huge thanks to him.

There is two sessions in Windows as Derek said, The lock screen is in session 0, also services work in session 0. And the Windows we use works in session 1. You cannot interfere to session 0 actively as I understand from session 1(correct me if I'm wrong please).

So we must execute the keystroke(sendInput as in the repo) program in session 0 but we must have the right privileges. Services seems to be the way because you can interfere with session 0 the way you want.

We must have another program to run as a service with the correct permissions.

The only program having the required permissions seems to be winlogon.exe, so we steal it's security token to our service program. Create our sendInput program in the correct desktop and it will type in the password.

Create Process code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wtsapi32.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include "TCHAR.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "Wtsapi32.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <direct.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wtsapi32.lib")

//must use this to return last error as stdout
std::string  GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    //get the error message id
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if (errorMessageID == 0) {
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded
    }

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;

    //why not ask win32 to give it as string
    //tell win32 to create the buffer that holds the message for us because we don't yet know how long the message string will be
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    //get that message as std::string.
    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);

    //free the dude
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}

//I can't find the process widiout widening its names string version
std::wstring widen(const std::string& str)
{
    //uncommented code here, just use
    std::wostringstream wstm;
    const std::ctype<wchar_t>& ctfacet = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(wstm.getloc());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        wstm << ctfacet.widen(str[i]);
    return wstm.str();
}

//return the process id, old code as widen() so uncommented
DWORD getProcess(std::string cstr)
{
    //widen and format the process' name because _tcsicmp is stupid(hes smarter than me)
    const std::wstring widestring = widen(cstr);
    const wchar_t* wcstr = widestring.c_str();

    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    DWORD sessionID = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    DWORD retval = 0;

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (_tcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, wcstr) == 0)
            {
                retval = entry.th32ProcessID;
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return retval;
}

bool isSessionLocked()
{
    WTSINFOEXW* pInfo = NULL;
    WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsic = WTSSessionInfoEx;
    LPTSTR ppBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
    LONG sessionFlags = WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNKNOWN; // until we know otherwise. Prevents a false positive since WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK == 0

    DWORD dwSessionID = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, dwSessionID, wtsic, &ppBuffer, &dwBytesReturned))
    {
        if (dwBytesReturned > 0)
        {
            pInfo = (WTSINFOEXW*)ppBuffer;
            if (pInfo->Level == 1)
            {
                sessionFlags = pInfo->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.SessionFlags;
            }
        }
        WTSFreeMemory(ppBuffer);
        ppBuffer = NULL;
    }

    return (sessionFlags == WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK);
}

void sendEnter()
{
    INPUT inputs[2] = {};
    ZeroMemory(inputs, sizeof(inputs));

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    SendInput(2, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
}

//install this codes deploy as a service otherwise we don't have enough permission to "steal" security token
int main()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    HANDLE hProcess;

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, getProcess("winlogon.exe"));

    if (hProcess == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "where logon?" << GetLastErrorAsString() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (!OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken))
    {
        std::cout << "doit get the process token, " << GetLastErrorAsString() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE hCurrentProcessToken;
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hCurrentProcessToken))
    {
        std::cout << "you cant even get your own token, how did you get winlogon.exe's??, " << GetLastErrorAsString() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken))
    {
        std::cout << "guess who's isnt a master in disguise, " << GetLastErrorAsString() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hCurrentProcessToken);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    LPTSTR lpCommandLine = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes = NULL;
    BOOL bInheritHandles = FALSE;
    DWORD dwCreationFlags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW;
    LPVOID lpEnvironment = NULL;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    STARTUPINFOA si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFOA));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);
    //we have to start the process in the login screen without a window, in line 169 if you want open a window idc
    std::string dg = "WinSta0\\WinLogOn";
    si.lpDesktop = const_cast<char*>(dg.c_str());
    //hide window even we didn't create a window
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        //start process using CreateProcessAsUserA
        //YOU CAN CHANGE THE DIRECTORY AND EXECUTABLES NAME HERE
        if (!CreateProcessAsUserA(hToken, "C:\\sendin\\sendPassword.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL,
            bInheritHandles, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, "C:\\sendin\\", &si, &pi))
        {
            std::cout << "CreateProcessAsUserA failed with error " << GetLastErrorAsString;
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

            DWORD exitCode;
            GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode);
            std::cout << "\nexitcode " << exitCode << std::endl;
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        }

        Sleep(1000);

        //in case of sending the wrong password
        if (isSessionLocked()) {
            sendEnter();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }

    //close handles
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(hCurrentProcessToken);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

sendInput:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void sendEnter() {
    INPUT inputs[2] = {};
    ZeroMemory(inputs, sizeof(inputs));

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    SendInput(2, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
}

void sendPassword() {
    std::map<std::string, WORD> keyMap;
    keyMap["Enter"] = 0x0D;
    keyMap["0"] = 0x30;    keyMap["1"] = 0x31;    keyMap["2"] = 0x32;    keyMap["3"] = 0x33;
    keyMap["4"] = 0x34;    keyMap["5"] = 0x35;    keyMap["6"] = 0x36;    keyMap["7"] = 0x37;
    keyMap["8"] = 0x38;    keyMap["9"] = 0x39;

    keyMap["A"] = 0x41;    keyMap["B"] = 0x42;    keyMap["C"] = 0x43;    keyMap["D"] = 0x44;
    keyMap["E"] = 0x45;    keyMap["F"] = 0x46;    keyMap["G"] = 0x47;    keyMap["H"] = 0x48;
    keyMap["I"] = 0x49;    keyMap["J"] = 0x4A;    keyMap["K"] = 0x4B;    keyMap["L"] = 0x4C;
    keyMap["M"] = 0x4D;    keyMap["N"] = 0x4E;    keyMap["O"] = 0x4F;    keyMap["P"] = 0x50;
    keyMap["Q"] = 0x51;    keyMap["R"] = 0x52;    keyMap["S"] = 0x53;    keyMap["T"] = 0x54;
    keyMap["U"] = 0x55;    keyMap["V"] = 0x56;    keyMap["W"] = 0x57;    keyMap["X"] = 0x58;
    keyMap["Y"] = 0x59;    keyMap["Z"] = 0x5A;

    //If you want to hardcode the password instead of reading it from the file, define it here and comment out the lines 42-48.
    std::string password = "PaSsWoRd";
    
    //Read the password from file.
    std::ifstream passFile("password.txt");
    if (!passFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open password file." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::getline(passFile, password);
    passFile.close();
    
    //Note here: I've tried many ways to send uppercase inputs but for the reasons I don't know a lot of them didn't work.
    //One works on Windows but magically doesn't work on Windows Server and only sends "@" as inputs etc.
    //Turning capslock on and off and waiting a bit seems the one it works normally.

    //If capslock is on, turn it off.
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0) {
        INPUT capsInputs[2] = {};
        ZeroMemory(capsInputs, sizeof(capsInputs));

        capsInputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        capsInputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_CAPITAL;

        capsInputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        capsInputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_CAPITAL;
        capsInputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        SendInput(2, capsInputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    }

    //It works better when you wait a while before sending another input.
    Sleep(500);

    //Iterate through the password string.
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
        std::string pasx(1, password[i]);
        //Check if uppercase.
        bool isUppercase = std::isupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(pasx[0]));
        //Get the uppercase to access from the map
        std::string keyVec(1, std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(pasx[0])));

        //If uppercase and capslock is off, turn it on.
        if (isUppercase && ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) == 0)) {
            INPUT capsInputs[2] = {};
            ZeroMemory(capsInputs, sizeof(capsInputs));

            capsInputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            capsInputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_CAPITAL;

            capsInputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            capsInputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_CAPITAL;
            capsInputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

            SendInput(2, capsInputs, sizeof(INPUT));
        }

        //Send the input.
        INPUT keyInputs[2] = {};
        ZeroMemory(keyInputs, sizeof(keyInputs));

        keyInputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        keyInputs[0].ki.wVk = keyMap[keyVec];

        keyInputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        keyInputs[1].ki.wVk = keyMap[keyVec];
        keyInputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        SendInput(2, keyInputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    
        //Turn off the capslock if its on.
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0) {
            INPUT capsInputs[2] = {};
            ZeroMemory(capsInputs, sizeof(capsInputs));

            capsInputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            capsInputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_CAPITAL;

            capsInputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            capsInputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_CAPITAL;
            capsInputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

            SendInput(2, capsInputs, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
    }

    //Turn off capslock
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0) {
        INPUT capsInputs[2] = {};
        ZeroMemory(capsInputs, sizeof(capsInputs));

        capsInputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        capsInputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_CAPITAL;

        capsInputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        capsInputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_CAPITAL;
        capsInputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        SendInput(2, capsInputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Sleep(200);
    sendPassword();
    sendEnter();
    Sleep(200);
    return 0;

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35705699)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you lock the screen, Windows changes which session is displayed for security reasons.  The usermode services and drivers runs in Session 0, and the first user to login runs in Session 1.  Essentially, `sendInput()` is sending the keystrokes to your desktop rather than the lock screen which is running in a different session:

[https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361#:~:text=The%20first%20user%20on%20the,used%20to%20target%20unsuspecting%20users.&text=In%20Windows%20Vista%2C%20Session%200,user%20run%20in%20Session%201](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361#:%7E:text=The%20first%20user%20on%20the,used%20to%20target%20unsuspecting%20users.&text=In%20Windows%20Vista%2C%20Session%200,user%20run%20in%20Session%201).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756986(v=msdn.10)

You may be able to work around this limitation with creative use of `CreateProcessAsUserA()` and specifying the desktop to use in the `lpStartupInfo` parameter (specifically, set the `lpDesktop` of the `STARTUPINFOA`).  This will involve having a small child program whose sole purpose is to unlock the screen, and have your parent process run the child process with `CreateProcessAsUserA()`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa

As a simpler (and probably more secure) alternative, have you tried using Remote Desktop?

Comment: Creating a program just to send input, and attaching it to a service so the session changes, and my main app will just restart the service. Can it work or is lock screen session and services session different?

Comment: It worked after struggling with it a few days. Thanks for the answer, accepted.

Comment: @Erz Impersonating security token of winlogon.exe and then starting the actual typing app with `CreateProcessAsUserA()`. You need your app to run as a service otherwise you cannot impersonate the security token as I remember. If you're still looking for it I can create a git repo

Comment: @kaankaya I'm still looking, could you create a repo? That would be great

Comment: @Erz I posted the repo in the answer. Hope it helps.
Thanks to Derek of course.