# Why SendInput() is not working for enter key on Lock screen?

Tags: c++, winapi, sendinput

I'm trying to simulate the "Enter key" using SendInput(), it is working on all the scenario's like SignOut, Restart, Shutdown etc.., except Lock.
Here's the code,

```
INPUT inputs[2] = { 0 };
ZeroMemory(inputs, sizeof(inputs));
inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;

inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
```

my question is, why it is not working on Lock Screen?
If this has no way to work, then how can I reach my purpose?
Does someone know whats the solution?

Comment: What *is* your purpose? Why do you need to send the `Enter` key to a lock screen? What is the original and actual problem that's supposed to solve? Please [edit] your question to ask us about the actual problem directly instead.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Logins occur in the Windows secure desktop.  Distinct from the user's desktop, it ensures that your code can't work.

Comment: I want to simulate enter key on lock screen to get the desktop with username and password fields on windows without clicking the enter button.

Comment: That code is working on Signout and Restart cases,  but on Lock it is not working, I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: @sireeshapallela Hans told you why. You can't programmically interact with the *secure* desktop externally. It wouldn't be secure anymore if you could.

Comment: If you were able to interact with key inputs on the lock screen, it'd cause serious security issues. You could have a keylogger running on your session and get the passwords of other people logging into your computer. Quite dangerous things, so as Hans said, you can't do anything from your session to the lock screen.

Comment: When I turned on my laptop, and I got to the lock screen with the time displayed, it would not open to let me enter my password. Everytime I hit a key or click the mouse it moves the screen up like it is going to let me enter my password.
Here, how I move the screen up programatically without pressing any key or click the mouse.

Comment: As [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75978542/15511041) said, the lock screen is running in session 0, a different session. Try to *SendInput* in the same session. As a sidenote, [This function is subject to UIPI. Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that are at an **equal or lesser** integrity level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput#remarks).